# How to define linear transformations: $\text{Ker }b \to \text{Ker } c,$ $\text{Im }b \to \text{Im } c,$ and $\text{Coker }b \to \text{Coker } c?$

Tags: linear-algebra, morphism

The following is taken from *linear algebra and geometry* by Leung

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

The $\textit{cokernel}$ of a linear transformation $c:X\to Y$ is defined as

$$\text{Coker }c=Y/\text{Im }c$$

$(a)$  Show that if the diagram of linear spaces and linear transformations $a$ and $d$ define linear transformations

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X  \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y \\
\end{array}$$

is commutative, then the linear transformations $\text{Ker }b \to \text{Ker } c,$ $\text{Im }b \to \text{Im } c,$ and $\text{Coker }b \to \text{Coker } c.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

For the exercise above, I am having trouble completing it due to not certain if my commutative diagrams are correct and also making use of the transformations given.

For the case of: $\text{Coker }b \to \text{Coker } c$

I think I have the following commutative diagram.

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c  \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y  \\
q'\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow q  \\
Y'/\text{Im }b & \xrightarrow{r} & Y/\text{Im }c \\
\end{array}\quad\quad (1)$$

I need to show the existence of $r:Y'/\text{Im }b\to Y/\text{Im }c$ as a linear transformation, and show that $c$ is linear.

For the existence part, I think I need to show that the explicit map for $r$ is $r(y'+\text{Im } b)=y+\text{Im } c$ exists.  I am having a difficult time doing so.

$r$ being well defined is pretty easy to show after showing its existence.  From commutative diagram $(1)$ we know that $c\cdot a = d\cdot b,$ we also have the following facts from the diagram:

$(q\cdot d)(y')=q(d(y'))=y+\text{Im }c$ and $(r\cdot q')(y')=r(q'(y'))=r(y'+\text{Im } b)$

I don't know how to make use of $c\cdot a = d\cdot b,$

For the case of: $\text{Ker }b \to \text{Ker } c$

I am not sure if the commutative diagram should either be

$$(a)\quad\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \text{Ker }b & \xrightarrow{w} & \text{Ker }c\\
m\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow n  \\
X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X   \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y  \\
\end{array} \text{or }\quad (b)  \quad\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X\\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c  \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y   \\
b^{-1}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c^{-1}   \\
\text{Ker }b & \xrightarrow{w} & \text{Ker }c \\
\end{array}\quad (2)$$

where $b^{-1}, c^{-1}$ both denote inverse image maps.

For the case of: $\text{Im }b \to \text{Im } c$

I think the commutative diagram might be:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c  \\
X'/\text{Ker }b & \xrightarrow{r} & X/\text{Ker }c \\
t\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow v   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{z} & Y  \\
\end{array}\quad (3)$$

where the linear transformations $t, v$ are suppose to be bijections.  I am trying to make use of the first isomorphism theorem for linear transformation for vector spaces. But I think it is suppose to be for the direct image of $b, c$ and not $t,v.$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Nota that for the kernel, you do *not* have an inverse map $b^{-1}$! The *defining* maps for kernel and cokernel are as follows (note the "dual" nature of theit respective arrows, which is also why the cokernel is called **co**kernel in the first place).
$$ \ker b\to X'\stackrel b\to Y'\to \operatorname{coker} b $$
The arrow on the left is the *canonical* inclusion (viewing the kernel as a subspace of $X'$), and the the arrow on the right is the *canonical* projection to the quotioent $Y'/\operatorname{im} b$.
Since these are the maps that you are granted automatically and without any choice or arbitrariness (you may learn more on that in the context of so-called *universality*), you should also try to construct the desired maps *only* from these.

So, combined you have
$$ \begin{matrix}\ker b&\to& X'&\to& Y'&\to& \operatorname{coker} b \\&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\ker c&\to& X&\to& Y&\to& \operatorname{coker} c 
\end{matrix}$$
You already found your way to define the maps between the cokernels: From $\operatorname{coker} b$ go left to $Y'$, then down to $Y$, then right to $\operatorname{coker} c$. In the first step, you made a choice, but can show that the final result is well-defined nevertheless.

For the kernels, you can in fact do the exact same thing (more precisely: the *dual* thing). Go right, down, left and give a conclusive argument why the go-left step is possible.